# Proof of Antisymmetry

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic, order-theory

I am stuck with proving antisymmetry under the natural numbers.
Prove "For each x,y E N, if x <= y and y <= x, then x=y.
I am not really sure where to start with this proof.  Im assuming I will need to prove it directly.
And I am only able to use defintion of addition, multiplication, and order in the natural numbers.
Any tips for this proof would be so greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!